# How to take a screenshot on iPhone X?

Tags: ios, iphone

As there is no Home button on iPhone X, how do you take a screenshot?
Swiping up from bottom of the screen while pressing the lock button?

Comment: Folks, it's a legitimate question answerable by anybody who has a chance to play with one of the demo models.

Comment: "Hey Siri, take a screenshot"?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That's way slower than using buttons. Not a great use for Siri.

Comment: @sgroves also Siri cannot take screenshots.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hold the **Side button** and tap **Volume Up**.

> #iPhoneX screenshot: Side button + Volume up

https://twitter.com/reneritchie/status/907736291726336000

Comment: But does it include a black bar on the top?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I’m curious about this too, so I asked [a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/298263/11572) about it.

Comment: I'm tempted to think I'd be taking a lot of accidental screenshots as I try to turn the phone off... on the 6S I often turn the volume up as I'm trying to do that :/

Comment: @Tetsujin on the flip side, I wonder how many people will accidentally restart their phone attempting to do a screenshot?

Answer (score 5):

Two Methods i found on Google,

Method 1:

Using Press, Side Button + Volume Up button at once.

Source: [Take a Screenshot on iPhone X: Alternate Ways](https://www.howtoisolve.com/how-take-screenshot-iphone-x-ios-11/)

Method 2:

Using Assistive touch, Really great for use on lock screen, Home screen or App Screen.

Comment: I like the assistive touch recommendation, a good alternative to keep in mind if you're doing a lot of these.

Comment: Doc on AssistiveTouch: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202658

Answer (score 1):

You apparently can do it by pressing the sleep/wake and the volume up button at the same time. Nevertheless, you can still take a screenshot with Assistive Touch in settings.

Comment: What's your source? [This doesn't match the info of this answer, which has a source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/298228/122523).

Answer (score 1):

One alternative way could be to use the new screen recording feature in iOS 11, and then from the video choose the image of choice.

Comment: That seems like a horrific workaround... Screenshots are usually quick 'spur of the moment' things that you don't want to start a whole, storage-intensive, screen recording for.

Comment: And you extract the frame of the video which is correct how?

Comment: Well as I also wrote it is an alternative way - maybe not the best, but still it is durable. When you have taken the video, you look it through, choose the image/frame you want with the app you want (it could be directly on the device, or transferred to a Mac/PC), from where you then store the image (some apps/tools let you do that).