# How is the top cutout handled in iPhone X screenshots?

Tags: ios, iphone

Along the lines of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298203/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-iphone-x)—if you take a screenshot on an iPhone X, how is the camera cutout at the top of the screen handled? Is there just a black region of the appropriate shape and size at the top of the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simulator behaves differently to an actual device. Screenshots from a real device do not have a cutout, nor rounded corners.

> Screenshots taken on iPhone X ignore the existence of the notch
>
> [image]

Guilherme Rambo on Twitter https://twitter.com/_inside/status/907743049220018176

Comment: Cool. Isn’t that too much space at the top looks a bit weird?

Comment: @Badhan Not any more weird than [how it looks pre-screenshot on real device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXpPb.png), I'm hardly a fan

Answer (score 2):

This is what I get when I take a screenshot from iPhone X simulator. Most probably this will be the result in real devices too:

[image]

**EDIT:**
The below screenshot was taken from iOS 11.3 simulator with Xcode 9.3. The cutout is not visible and it resembles screenshot from a real device.

[image: Screenshot from latest iOS simulator]

Comment: Any idea why there are black bars along the sides?

Comment: I’ve edited my answer. @bdesham

Comment: (I'm probably getting this phone, but) Wow this looks silly. Still don't know how I feel about a chunk of my screen missing.

Comment: @Alan I’m fine with it. Because the alternative is what we have now where the screen is smaller and has a bezel. Then the status bar takes up some more of the screen (granted, not a lot, especially since iPhone 5). I see it as: “hey, there’s unused space on the front on the sides of the speaker and camera. What if we put the time and battery percentage up there?” I’m sure if it were possible, there wouldn’t be a cutout and instead, the sensors are under the screen and the nearby pixels turned off temporarily to take pictures.

Comment: This answer is from the simulator and does not reflect the result from a real device.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you got the simulator to not show the rounded corners of the iPhone X? Black rounded corners always appear in simulator. Thanks!